# Como acessar um ManagedBean através de um arquivo js externo?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf

Como eu faço para acessar um managed bean jsf através de um arquivo javascript externo? Estou tentando acessar da seguinte forma:

```
  $("#botaoCadastroMaterial").click(function(){
   '#{cadastroMaterialController.salvar()}'; 
});
```

porém nao esta funcionando.

abaixo segue meu xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    template="../template/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="corpoPagina">
        <div id="divCadastroMaterial">
        <h1 style="width:100%;text-align:center;">Cadastro de Material</h1>
            <h:form prependId="false" id="formularioCadastroMaterial">
                <h:outputLabel value="Titulo"/>
                <h:inputText class="form-control"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Categoria"/>
                <h:inputText class="form-control"/> 
                <h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" value="Cadastrar" id="botaoCadastroMaterial"/>
            </h:form>               
        </div>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Preciso que, quando acionado um botao no xhtml, seja executado uma função no meu arquivo js, que tem como implementação a chamada de um metodo do meu managed bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. cria um botão onde a action seja o que vc deseja

`<h:commandButton action="#{cadastroMaterialController.salvar()}"/>`

2. cria um id para esse botão

`<h:commandButton id="botao_fantasma_para_chamar_via_js" action="#{cadastroMaterialController.salvar()}"/>`

3. deixa ele invisível

`<h:commandButton id="botao_fantasma_para_chamar_via_js" action="#{cadastroMaterialController.salvar()}" style="display: none" />`

4. faça a chamada da da action por:

`$("#botao_fantasma_para_chamar_via_js").click()`

Comment: po, vou fazer dessa forma mesmo então, valeu ae cara.